# How to assign value to a variable on Django template through jQuery

Tags: django

I have a Django template file working with a passed value like the below.

```
{% include 'boutique/rating.html' with score=[I want to put value here] %}
```

When I usually put value into the template, I could easily do it by doing like the below.

```
{% for store in stores %}
    {% include 'boutique/rating.html' with score=store.review_score %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, as I get into more complex templates, I need to assign the value to the score parameter in the include section through jQuery. Is there a way that I can acheive this through jQuery?

Comment: By "put the value through jQuery", what do you mean? Do you need to get the value from django and process it with jQuery? Or are you somehow trying to use jQuery to get the value and then send it to the django server?

Comment: Sorry for making confusion. Just edited that part.

Comment: I get the value from another template and process it in jQuery and then wanna pass it to the include section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to understand is this: The part of the template between `{%` and `%}` is interpreted by Django. It is processed entirely on the server. In other words, it never shows up in the browser, but gets replaced by some sort of standard HTML.

On the other hand, jQuery is a Javascript library and operates *entirely* in the browser -- it doesn't know anything about the server or Django.

So, to modify the included template with jQuery, you have to find out what HTML it renders to. You can probably do that by looking at the included template file. Then, treat that HTML the way you would any other part of the page for manipulation with jQuery.

Comment: Was going for the wrong direction. Thank you for clarifying that!